# How to skip cucumber tests during build & deployment when unit test runs but after deployment it should run cucumber tests via Jenkins - Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have a build project in which i implemented Cucumber BDD and wrote features file and test classes. Now, what i want is that during build & deployment in Jenkins pipeline, all Unit tests should get executed but not the Cucumber tests i.e. Integration tests. As soon as deployment is completed then these cucumber tests should get executed. How we can achieve that? 
Is there any way to skip cucumber test during the deployment but after the deployment completion it should execute them?

Answer (score 0):

You can tag your tests with annotations as `@Deploy` and `@AfterDeploy`,

To maven deployment script, you can add following script :

`-Dcucumber.options="--tags @Deploy"`

For the tests after deployment you can use following :

`-Dcucumber.options="--tags @AfterDeploy"`